# Why does zinc turn dark?

Tags: metal, elements, metallurgy

So I casted a zinc ingot around a week ago and I also casted 2 zinc ingots yesterday. After observing the two side by side I noticed that the older zinc ingot was darker colored, then I went and looked at all of my old ingots containing zinc. They where all dark. Here is a picture of the old one and the new one side by side

[image]

The old ingot is on the left and the new one is on the right.

Here is another photo[image]

Is this oxidation possibly? What causes this? Any answers are appreciated.

Comment: Give this a read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zinc#Reactivity Apparently the dark film is that of zinc carbonate ;)